# Jquery slider not working multiple call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

below is my code for jquery slider ....

```
function slide_temp(min,max){

    $('#myrange_range').noUiSlider({
    start: [min, max],
    connect: true,
    range: {
        'min': 16,
        'max': 30
    },
    orientation: 'vertical',
    behaviour: 'tap-drag',
    margin: 1,
    setp: 1,
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0
    }),
    direction: "rtl"
    });
}
```

I have to call this function on every `<li>` click by passing `min and max parameters` First Clicks it works well but from second click on words I get and error on console and clider stops working...

`Uncaught Error: Slider was already initialized.`

Is there any ways to uninitialize plugin ?? and any other way to fix this problem?

Comment: @Verhaeren I know that we can not initialize the object more than once, so iam asking how to uninitialize an object... so that i can uninitialize it before reinitilizeing.. or can you tell me how to "You first initialize the object and then apply a method of the object" I want to initilize to only one object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the slider outside of your function

```
$('#myrange_range').noUiSlider({
    start: [minval, maxval], // Pass your init values here.
    connect: true,
    range: {
        'min': 16,
        'max': 30
    },
    orientation: 'vertical',
    behaviour: 'tap-drag',
    margin: 1,
    setp: 1,
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0
    }),
    direction: "rtl"
});
```

Then create a function which updates the values [make sure to call `updateSlider` after the plugin is initialized]

```
function updateSlider(min,max){
    $('#myrange_range').val([min,max]);
}
```

[More info](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#myrange_range" ).noUiSlider( options, true /* Allow destruction + rebuilding */ );
```